# Unit testing Placeholder defaultValue in @RequestParam

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking, mockmvc

I'm trying to test my controller that has a handler with a RequestParam configured with a default value pointed to a placeholder:

```
@Controller     
public class AgeController {
    @GetMapping("/age")
    public String home(@RequestParam(name="current", defaultValue="${default.age}") Integer age) {
        return "age"+age;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I'm testing through my browser but when I use the following test case, it throws an exception:

Test Case:

```
public class AgeControllerTest {
    AgeController controller
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before 
    public void setUp() {
        ageController = new AgeController();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).addPlaceholderValue("default.age", "10").build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/age")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${default.age}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:468)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:441)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:713)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using @TestPropertySource.

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"default.age = 10"})
public class AgeControllerTest {
    ...
}
```